# References for MVP for Android

Tags: android, blogs, dagger-2, realm-mobile-platform, android-mvp

I want to implement MVP pattern for my Android application along with Dagger and RealmDB. I am a complete noob in these concepts. I have referred https://android.jlelse.eu/mvp-dagger-2-rx-clean-modern-android-app-code-74f63c9a6f2f . The blog post though good lacks a bit of explanation about the code demonstrated.

Can anyone recommend good blog posts with explanations which I can follow to implement MVP, Dagger and RealmDb in my app? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can I ask you a question?Why MVP or RealmDb?

Comment: I learned from here https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture

Comment: @mahdishahbazi I have worked on RealmDb before for Android and found it pretty straight forward and efficient. MVP because I want to stucturize my project better for future development and also want to implement Android unit tests. But if you can recommend any better combination that would be great too.

Comment: OK,because it's long I write it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

first I say check ORM's benchmark and choice your decide about your ORM. Don't worry about learning new ORM because it's too easy. here is a benchmark of ORM's [ORM's benchmark](https://github.com/AlexeyZatsepin/Android-ORM-benchmark)

***Architecture One***

first choice is using MVVM. This is a good architecture that you can find many article and blogs in internet. The best benefit if MVVM is you can use is beside data binding that is a great library that support by google and is very useful. Databinding make your project more scale-able and easy to maintenance.

***Architecture two***

Second Article is going beyond MVVM and databinding. It's using [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/) . It's couples of component's that introduce and support by google. this components include Databinding,LiveData,Lifecycle,ViewModel,RoomDB,... that google has a good documentation for them and how to use them together.
benefits of this architecture can find in this sentence from google:

> Android architecture components are a collection of libraries that
>   help you design robust, testable, and maintainable apps